# Autoselect Radio Button on pageload

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to automatically select a radio button 2-3 seconds after you visit the page

Website: https://livishparis.com/products/pheromone-balm-buy-one-get-two

There I want that the "buy 2 get 4" button is pressed a few seconds after the page is visited. How can I do this?
Thank you <3

Comment: The solution depends on the e-commerce site used, but for a simple html page you could just use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or alternatively use a [css transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) Note that the radio buttons would require custom styling to make them look like your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new script:

```
<script src="auto_check.js">
```

in the script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio-1').click();
    document.getElementById('buy-two-get-four').click();
}, 2000) // 1000 is one second
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, why is the radio 1 needed?

Comment: i dont know the structure of the website i assumed thet the radio button and buy-2-get-4 button are different, you get the idea, work around it :), and make sure to select the most correct answer

Comment: Yo thank you. I mixed your answer with Bahubali Ak's answer together (your timer and his getelementbyid part) and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with JS as shown below

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("your_radio_button_id_goes_here").checked = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you look at the website now it selects the "buy 2 get 4" button (at least the border gets big) but it's not actually selected since the 19.95 price is still showing and it should be 39.95. The button doesn't seem to actually be clicked. You know a workaround? (The script is in the bottom div class="product-block" if you inspect element)

Comment: Actually got it working with a timout. THX!